# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, random, substring

I have a piece of code that generates random characters. The problem is, every once in a while, it returns an error: 
**"startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"**

How do I prevent this kind of error from happening?

Here's my code:

```
Friend Function gentCtrlChar()
    Dim ran As New Random
    Dim alpha As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim alpha2 As String = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
    Dim rdm As New Random
    Dim genChar As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 1 To 52
        Dim selChar As Integer = rdm.Next(1, 28)
        Dim selChar2 As Integer = rdm.Next(1, 28)
        genChar = genChar + "" + alpha.Substring(selChar, 1) + "" + alpha2.Substring(selChar2, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Exit For
    Next
    Return genChar
End Function
```

as you can see, I tried putting the "On Error Resume Next" hoping that somehow, this will take care of the error for me. But sadly, It doesn't do it's job. Or am I using it the wrong way or for the wrong situation?

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: There are only 26 chars in the alphabet/your alpha strings.  `rdm.Next(1, 28)` is setting an upper limit of 28 (2 too many).

Comment: Plus it will never get the first character of the string, since the index of the first character is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code:

```
Dim selChar As Integer = rdm.Next(1, 28)
```

will sometimes return a number that is longer (27 or 28) than the length of this string:

```
Dim alpha As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"  (only 26 characters long)
```

so, this is invalid when selChar is 26 or more.

```
alpha.Substring(selChar, 1)
```

Easiest fix is:

```
Dim selChar As Integer = rdm.Next(0, alpha.Length) 
Dim selChar2 As Integer = rdm.Next(0, alpha2.Length)
```

Comment: This needs to be tweaked still.  Since `String.Substring` uses a zero based indexer, the correct range would be `rdm.Next(0, 25)`.  As is, the first chars would never get picked and it would still error out when 26 comes up.  `"0123456789".Substring(1,1)` is "1" not "0".

Comment: @Plutonix, what do you mean by "String.Substring uses a zero based indexer"?

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix ... you're right ... I've modified my answer.

Comment: @Plutonix - `rdm.Next(0, 25)` will never return the last character.  The second parameter of the Next method is the _exclusive_ upper value.  You need `rdm.Next(0, 26)` or as BWS showed, `rdm.Next(0, alpha.Length)` to include all characters.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks, I didnt know it was exclusive...I would never use literal values anyway, but something like `alpha.length` and so avoid both the problem and even having to know that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.  I think its cleaner and easy to understand. A - Z is the same as 65 - 90 on the ascii map so its very easy to convert an integer into a Char value.  Then we just use the string builder to make this easier to read.

```
Dim rdm As New Random
Dim genChar As New StringBuilder()
For i As Integer = 1 To 52
    Dim selChar As Char = Chr(rdm.Next(65, 90))
    Dim selChar2 As Char = Chr(rdm.Next(65, 90))
    genChar.Append(selChar)
    genChar.Append(selChar2)
Next
Return genChar.ToString
```